# How do i get first day of year whe i select year in parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

IN SSRS 
I am trying to get first day of year when i select only year in parameter.
I know how to make it in SQL.
e.g. when i select 2020 in paramater i must get 01.01.2020 as output
when i select 2019 in paramater i must get 01.01.2019 as output

**i tried to get by
DateAdd("d",-DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear,Today,0,0)+1,Today) 
 here i get 1st day of year, but i am not getting where should i replace with my year parameter**
Can someone please help me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your year parameter is just a simple integer then you can just do.

```
=DateSerial(Parameters!myYearParam.Value, 1, 1)
```